# Unable to get property 'Gallery' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, runtime, unhandled

I'm getting this error in Internet Explorer:

> Unhandled exception at line 1, column 106 in http://localhost:50981/Scripts/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'Gallery' of undefined or null reference

I am using bootstrap and blue imp gallery in my website project.

I've tried reordering script links to no avail.

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: It's probably something you're doing. Can you post your code where you use 'Gallery'?

Comment: (function (factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([
            'jquery',
            './blueimp-gallery'
        ], factory);
    } else {
        factory(
            window.jQuery,
            window.blueimp.Gallery
        );
    }

Comment: }(function ($, Gallery) {
    'use strict';

    $.extend(Gallery.prototype.options, {
        useBootstrapModal: true
    });

    var close = Gallery.prototype.close,
        imageFactory = Gallery.prototype.imageFactory,
        videoFactory = Gallery.prototype.videoFactory,
        textFactory = Gallery.prototype.textFactory;

    $.extend(Gallery.prototype, {